# Shortcuts for each feature

Tags: wix

I'm writing an installer that contains a root feature and three nested features:

```
<Feature Id="FEATURE_BasicLibraries" Title="Basic Libraries" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG_RequiredLibraries" />
  <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Shortcuts" />

  <Feature Id="FEATURE_App1" Title="App1" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG_App1" />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="FEATURE_App2" Title="App2" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG_App2" />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="FEATURE_App3" Title="App3" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG_App3" />
  </Feature>
</Feature>
```

each nested feature contains an exe file that represents an applications installed by the feature. The root feature is simply a set of necessary Dlls.

I'm willing to create three shortcuts in the start menu. Here is how I do it:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ShortcutsFolder">
  <Component Id="CMP_Shortcuts" Guid="378C7AC2-9FA0-4895-A3A1-E7526B673BB4">
    <Shortcut Id="App1MenuShortcut" Name="App1" Target="[InstallFolder]App1.exe"/>
    <Shortcut Id="App2MenuShortcut" Name="App2" Target="[InstallFolder]App2.exe"/>
    <Shortcut Id="App3MenuShortcut" Name="App3" Target="[InstallFolder]App3.exe"/>
    <Shortcut Id="UninstallShortcut" Name="Uninstall" Target="[SystemFolder]\msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" />

    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShortcutsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\AppSuite" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

When I install my product I see all the three shortcuts (in fact four, including Uninstall) no matter what features I chose. How to make the installer create shortcuts only for installed features?

The only solution I see is to create several components for each shortcut. The solution is straightforwrad, but then I will need to create three `<RegistryValue>` tags inside of each component. How to deal with `<RemoveFolder>` tag in this case?

Are there other solutions?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since level of all features are 1, everytime its gone create shortcuts for all. Create customaction that will be called when features are selected and un-selected and assign that value to some session variable. Use those session variable to make level of individual feature 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one component for each shortcut. Windows Installer doesn't do "partial" components. Each component can have its own `RemoveFolder` and `RegistryValue` entries.